# Make 'onEdit' work only on one of the sheets in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have an 'onEdit' script for a Google Sheets but only want it to work on one sheet:

```
    function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var CellRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var CellColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn();

  if (CellColumn == 2 && CellRow == 3){
    sheet.getRange(CellRow, CellColumn).setFormula( "=ArrayFormula(QUERY(ImportRange(\"0AmH7M5970cwZdHFRa3NITkdBSFhxd3JzYUZwbFRId3c\";\"Table!B2:J200\");\"select Col1 where Col1 = \'\"&$K$13&\"\' limit 1\"))");
    Browser.msgBox("DON'T MESS WITH THE FORMULAS!");
  }
  }
```

How to I change the script so that it only works on one of the sheets in the worksheet?

Comment: Here is also the url to the google doc:       https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiZUQMvsVudJdFpMbjdJTlpzVGxacDl4YlRyV2NaZ1E#gid=0

Comment: Nevermind, I've got the answer on this site: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?p=1239551#post1239551

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var CellRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var CellColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn();

  if (sheet.GetSheetName() == "MYSHEETNAME"){
    if (CellColumn == 2 && CellRow == 3){
    sheet.getRange(CellRow, CellColumn).setFormula( "=ArrayFormula(QUERY(ImportRange(\"0AmH7M5970cwZdHFRa3NITkdBSFhxd3JzYUZwbFRId3c\";\"Table!B2:J200\");\"select Col1 where Col1 = \'\"&$K$13&\"\' limit 1\"))");
    Browser.msgBox("DON'T MESS WITH THE FORMULAS!");
    }
  }
}
```

Change `MYSHEETNAME` to the name of the sheet you want onedit to work for.